# Even if I specify the type when passing the setState function as props, a type error seems to occur

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-ishizaka-140bq4?file=/src/App.tsx

An error occurs when sending props to the `TagInput` component.

> `SetStateAction<Props[]>` can't assign `string[]`

In `TagInput.tsx` nothing error. Please Check it..

Answer (score 3):

You are over complicating it. You only need to pass the type of your props to your [`useState`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L916) generic.

Instead of :

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";
import TagInput from "./TagInput";

type Props = {
  tags: string[];
  setTags: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<SetStateAction<Props[]>>([]);
  return (
    <>
      <TagInput tags={tags} setTags={setTags} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

do this:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from "react";
import TagInput from "./TagInput";

type Props = {
  tags: string[];
  setTags: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string[]>>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>([]);
  return (
    <>
      <TagInput tags={tags} setTags={setTags} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The Props type is useless.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-water-p0tbnm?file=/src/App.tsx:0-353)